# how to customize porc freq to deal with missing values

Tags: sas

I have the following code

```
data work.customBins;
   retain fmtname 'bins' type 'n';
   do binStart=-2.5 to 2.45 by 0.05;
      binEnd=binStart+0.05;
      difference=cat(binStart," to ",binEnd);
      output;
  end;
run;
proc format library=work cntlin=work.customBins; run;

proc freq data=work.myData;
  table variable /missing;
  format variable bins.;
run;
```

This code works properly everything is fine my only issue is If I have bins for example **-1.45 to -1.40** that dont have any values proc freq disregards  them. I want the cumulative frequency of the pervious bin to be displayed in the bins that have no values for example

-1.50 to -.145 cumulative Freq = 2%

-.1.45 to -1.4 has no values but the cumulative Freq for this  should be 2%

I have also tried doing this

```
data work.combined;
   set work.myData (in=a)  work.customBins (in=b)
   if a then cont=1;
   if b then cont=0;
run;

proc freq data=work.combined;
  table variable /missing;
  format variable bins.;
  weight cont/zeros;
run;
```

But this also does not work

myData just contains a single variabrle called **variable** which  is decimal numbers in the range of -2.45 to 2.45

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working variant:

```
data work.customBins;
    do binStart=-2.5 to 2.45 by 0.05;
    binEnd=binStart+0.05;
    difference=cat(binStart," to ",binEnd);
    output;
end;
run;

proc sql;
    create table want as
    select difference, count(variable)  as count
    from  customBins left join mydata
    on binStart < variable <= binEnd
    group by difference
    order by binStart;
quit;

proc freq data=want order=data;
    tables  difference;
    weight count / zeros;
run;
```

Regarding your first variant. Are you sure that your PROC FORMAT works as expected? Dataset used in CNTLIN-option should have variables START, END and LABEL, not voluntarily named ones. Anyway, it wouldn't work because PROC FREQ uses only values that you do have in mydata dataset, doesn't matter how many other labels you defined in your format.

Comment: you are honestly a legend I have asked this question so many times but your solution work thank you so much I really apperciate it thank you so much.